# Extracting English imperative mood from verb tags with spaCy

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I would like to detect the imperative mood of verbs in English sentences. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755559/how-to-extract-tag-attributes-using-spacy) I'm aware that spaCy has access to extended morphological features, but I don't see them when I use it, using spaCy version 2.1.8, Python 3.7.1:

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
>>> doc = nlp("Show me the money!")
>>> token = doc[0]
>>> print(token, token.tag_, nlp.vocab.morphology.tag_map[token.tag_], token.pos_, token.dep_)
Show VB {74: 100, 'VerbForm': 'inf'} VERB ROOT
```

Looks like spaCy correctly inferred that "show" is a verb, but it appears that it thinks it's an infinitive, and I see no mood information from the `tag_map`. I realize that this extended information is available in my linked question because Italian was being parsed there and determining the mood may be simpler for Romance-inflected verbs.

In any case, does any extended information about mood exist for verbs in English sentences?