# How can I enhance morphological information for English models in spaCy?

Tags: nlp, pos-tagger, spacy-3

I am trying to detect verbs that are in the imperative mood using English models in spaCy but I am seeing morphological features that are inconsistent with the examples found in the [Morphology](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#morphology) documentation. This issue is similar to this unanswered [Extracting English imperative mood from verb tags with spaCy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59008046/72992) question. Specifically, there seems to very few [mood](https://universaldependencies.org/u/feat/Mood.html) features identified.

I am not sure if I am missing some configuration or if I need to somehow train the model to better identify morphological features. Before I go down the path of training, I'd like to understand why what I am doing is not matching the documentation.

I have written a small example that demonstrates the discrepancy.

```
'''
Prerequisites

pip install spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
'''
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

def show_morph_as_markdown_table(doc):
    print("|Context|Token|Lemma|POS|TAG|MORPH|")
    print("|----|----|----|----|----|----|")
    for token in doc:
        print(f'|{doc}|{token.text}|{token.lemma_}|{token.pos_}|{token.tag_}|{token.morph.to_dict()}|')

def show_morph_for_sentences_as_markdown_table(sentences):
    sentence_docs = list(nlp.pipe(sentences))
    for sentence_doc in sentence_docs:
        show_morph_as_markdown_table(sentence_doc)

example_sentences = [
    "I was reading the paper",
    "I don’t watch the news, I read the paper",
    "I read the paper yesterday"
]

show_morph_for_sentences_as_markdown_table(example_sentences)
```

I have trimmed the output to include only rows shown in the [Morphology](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#morphology) documentation.

| Context | Token | Lemma | POS | TAG | MORPH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I was reading the paper | reading | read | VERB | VBG | {'Aspect': 'Prog', 'Tense': 'Pres', 'VerbForm': 'Part'} |
| I don’t watch the news, I read the paper | read | read | VERB | VBD | {'Tense': 'Past', 'VerbForm': 'Fin'} |
| I read the paper yesterday | read | read | VERB | VBP | {'Tense': 'Pres', 'VerbForm': 'Fin'} |

This is very different from the expected output of:

| Context | Token | Lemma | POS | TAG | MORPH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I was reading the paper | reading | read | VERB | VBG | {'VerbForm': 'Ger'} |
| I don’t watch the news, I read the paper | read | read | VERB | VBD | {'VerbForm': 'Fin', 'Mood': 'Ind', 'Tense': 'Pres'} |
| I read the paper yesterday | read | read | VERB | VBP | {'VerbForm': 'Fin', 'Mood': 'Ind', 'Tense': 'Past'} |

I've tried adding a morphologizer to the pipeline using the DEFAULT_MORPH_MODEL but was met with an initialization error. I don't know enough about the pipeline yet to understand why.

```
from spacy.pipeline.morphologizer import DEFAULT_MORPH_MODEL

config = {"model": DEFAULT_MORPH_MODEL}
nlp.add_pipe("morphologizer", config=config)

# ValueError: [E109] Component 'morphologizer' could not be run. Did you forget to call `initialize()`?

# trying to fix above error with the following
nlp.initialize()

# [E955] Can't find table(s) lexeme_norm for language 'en' in spacy-lookups-data. Make sure you have the package installed or provide your own lookup tables if no default lookups are available for your language.
```

In researching further, it appears that spaCy version 3 [manages tag_map and morph_rules with AttributeRuler](https://spacy.io/usage/v3#migrating-training-mappings-exceptions). Could it be possible that the downloadable models aren't including the same information that the documentation is using?

I'm hoping for an easy configuration fix that I am missing or a pointer to the right rabbit hole (I've been down many).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table is the docs is just meant to be a generic example of the kinds of annotation you might see, and the exact annotation from each individual model may be different, also for each individual release/version of a model.

You're not going to have much luck detecting imperatives using the `en_core_web_*` models because the training data doesn't distinguish imperatives from other forms. The rules that handle the tagset conversion are largely based on this table (note that there's no `Mood=Imp` for any PTB tag):

https://universaldependencies.org/tagset-conversion/en-penn-uposf.html

However, it does look like some of the UD English corpora do include `Mood=Imp` or use fine-grained tags that distinguish imperatives. To start out, you could test out a pretrained UD English EWT model from a tool like Stanza or Trankit to see if that works well enough for your task. It can be a difficult distinction to make, so I don't know how good the overall performance might be, though.

If you'd like to keep working with spacy, you could use `spacy-stanza` with the default "en" models, which are trained on UD English EWT.